# How to avoid to having to write each reference to each element in an initializer list of a vector of pointers?

Tags: c++

-If possible- how could I avoid to manually write each reference to each element one by one?
-If not possible-, what could I do to circumvent this problem?

(Where I put '...' I mean 'from to')

*EDIT: I don't need the ref_int_vec to contain the pointers to ALL the int_vect's elements, but only for some, and I believe that it would be faster and less error-prone to type something similar to this than many loops*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> int_vect{0,30000,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13};
    std::vector<const int*> ref_int_vect{&int_vect[1], &int_vect[3]...&int_vect[6], &int_vect[8], &int_vect[10]...&int_vect[13]};
    for (size_t i{0}; i != ref_int_vect.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << *ref_int_vect[i] << '\n';
    //*(ref_int_vect[0])/=10;
    //std::cout << *ref_int_vect[0] << ' ' << int_vect[1];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not just use a for loop?  If you are worried about extra allocations, you can do `ref_int_vect.reserve(int_vect.size());` to guarantee only a single allocation

Comment: Please explain why using a runtime loop for something that systematic is not the answer. Especially since the loop seems to be already there and only needs another statement inside.

Comment: @NathanOliver I need the ref_int_vect to contain only some pointers to the some elements of int_vect, do you mean I should write many for loops?

Comment: It looks like you code follows a pattern and if that is the case it should be one or possibly two, with one loop nested in the other.